# Yocto: Overriding function in existing recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am new to Yocto. I am trying to modify an existing function in a recipe. I am a little confused on how to override the function using a bbappend file.

I have the following code in an existing recipe:

```
fn_functionA () {
    pushd ${WORKDIR}/folder1
    git submodule update --init --recursive submodule1
    popd
}
do_unpack[postfuncs] += "fn_functionA"
```

I need to edit this function to the following:

```
fn_functionA () {
        pushd ${WORKDIR}/folder1
        git submodule update --init --recursive submodule1
        popd
        pushd ${WORKDIR}/folder1/submodule1
        git fetch "ssh link to project" refs/changes/99/68099/1 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
        popd
    }
    do_unpack[postfuncs] += "fn_functionA"
```

Do I need to copy/paste the whole body of the edited function in the bbappend file, or do an addtask? A detailed answer would be appreciated.

Also, n00b question: Why can't we edit the bb file and modify the function directly instead of overriding the function in a bbappend file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append to functions the same way as you append to recipe's tasks.

Here is an example:

- `meta-example/recipes-example/example/example_0.1.bb`

```bash
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

func_example() {
    bbwarn "From func_example"
}

do_example() {
    bbwarn "From do_example"
}

do_example[postfuncs] += "func_example"
addtask do_example
```

Now when you run: `bitbake example -c example` you should see:

```
...
WARNING: example-0.1-r0 do_example: From do_example
WARNING: example-0.1-r0 do_example: From func_example
...
```

Now, let's create a `bbappend` file:

- `meta-example-2/recipes-example/example/example_%.bbappend`

```bash
func_example_append() {
    bbwarn "From func_example_append"
}
```

Now, when you run `bitbake example -c example` again you should see:

```bash
...
WARNING: example-0.1-r0 do_example: From do_example
WARNING: example-0.1-r0 do_example: From func_example
WARNING: example-0.1-r0 do_example: From func_example_append
...
```

EDIT: If you want to override the function, just redefine it without `append` or `prepend`, in my example it would be:

```bash
func_example() {
    bbwarn "From func_example_append"
}
```

And the output would be:

```bash
...
WARNING: example-0.1-r0 do_example: From do_example
WARNING: example-0.1-r0 do_example: From func_example_append
...
```

### Why using `bbappend` ?

It is not recommended to change/edit something directly in a third party Yocto layer (Example: meta-raspberrypi, meta-qt5, ...), and here is why:

- By time, you will forget what you changed.
- No one can replicate your exact image unless you send it your modified layer
- If you want to upgrade the layer from one release to another, you need to manually redo the modifications unless you did not forget them
- It is not a way to work in a Yocto development team
- Creating a `bbappend` in your custom layer gives clear idea of what you have changed, also it will be easy to update the changes or to send the layer to someone knows that he should clone the third party by him self and then use your layer.

The most import point for me, is a respect for those who developed the layer and make it public for everyone, that is why keeping it clean as cloned is one of the best practices techniques in Yocto development.

Comment: How would the structure of the bbappend work if I wanted to extend some recipe that I did not write? Your .bbappend here is in the same directory. What if I wanted to append, for instance, `openssh`?

Comment: The bbappend is in `meta-example-2` which is another layer, the same path inside the layers is recommended and not mandatory. You can created the bbappend wherever you want in `recipes-*/*/*.bbappend` , for openssh it would be: `meta-yourlayer/recipes-connectivity/openssh/openssh_%.bbappend` for any version or specify exact version you want to append to.

Comment: I missed the rename, thanks for the clarification. I was able to get this working. However, I am also interested in _patching_ (with a patch file) some SRC_URI files from the original recipe. From what I understand, it looks like the patches are applied to the source dir of the project, not the working dir of the original recipe (which seems to be where its SRC_URI files are copied/cloned into. Any idea?

Comment: For future reference is looks like you can add arguments to [SRC_URI](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-SRC_URI) _per element_. So you can achieve what I am looking for here by using `patchdir` and maybe `striplevel`. So e.g. `SRC_URI:append = "file://0099-an-example.patch;patchdir=${WORKDIR};striplevel=0"`.